# Is it possible to remove the highlighted menu on Users and highlight a different menu?

Tags: menus, dashboard

In the WordPress dashboard on the users page if on filtering by a certain user role I don't want the parent Users menu to be highlighted - this is because I am going to link to that from another menu.

Is it possible to do this? I have attempted to do it using the parent_menu filter but this doesn't work when trying to unhighlight the standard dashboard parent menus, I can do it if it isn't a standard one such as my own post type, but not users.php

I have attempted all the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308569/manually-highlight-wordpress-admin-menu-item with no luck.

Is there anyway to achieve this or does WordPress simply not take the parent_file filter into account when setting it's own active menu items for core menu pages?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, functions of this page will help you: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page
Take your time, understand these removing functions and you'll be done in no time

Comment: Sorry, but removing a menu page is not what I was asking - I wanted the core menu page to remain but that menu not be highlighted when accessed via a link in another menu item with a specific query var. I can't solve this issue myself.